# Adding attributes to existing elements, removing elements, etc with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I parse in the XML using

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('test.xml', etree.XMLParser())
```

Now I want to work on the parsed XML. I'm having trouble removing elements with namespaces or just elements in general such as

```
<rdf:description><dc:title>Example</dc:title></rdf:description>
```

and I want to remove that entire element as well as everything within the tags. I also want to add attributes to existing elements as well.  The methods I need are in the `Element` class but I have no idea how to use that with the `ElementTree` object here.  Any pointers would definitely be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get to the root element via this call: `root=tree.getroot()`

Using that root element, you can use `findall()` and remove elements that match your criteria:

```
deleteThese = root.findall("title")
for element in deleteThese: root.remove(element)
```

Finally, you can see what your new tree looks like with this: `etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)`

Here is some info about how find/findall work:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/class-ElementTree.html#ElementTree-find

To add an attribute to an element, try something like this:

```
root.attrib['myNewAttribute']='hello world'
```

Comment: any idea on how i would find funky tags such as <rdf:description>?

Comment: @axsuul Did you figure how to add the funky tags?

Comment: @ShreedharManek sorry it's been so long since this project. I don't remember!

Comment: @axsuul Haha, I hadn't noticed the date until after the comment! Someone else helped me with it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714813/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-a-tag-found-using-xpath-in-lxml-in-python/37715285?noredirect=1#comment62904323_37715285)!

Comment: adding attributes does not seem working.  I am using WIN10 and got the following error message: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 30, "e.attrib['actionableInside'] = False"))

Answer (score 1):

The `remove` method should do what you want:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from StringIO import StringIO

>>> s = '<Root><Description><Title>foo</Title></Description></Root>'
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(s))

>>> print(etree.tostring(tree.getroot()))
<Root><Description><Title>foo</Title></Description></Root>

>>> title = tree.find('//Title')
>>> title.getparent().remove(title)
>>> etree.tostring(tree.getroot())
'<Root><Description/></Root>'

>>> print(etree.tostring(tree.getroot()))
<Root><Description/></Root>
```