# Insert attribute to a particular node in XML file

Tags: python, xml, linux

I have an XML with the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TagA attr1="abs" attrB="mdf">
  <TagB>
    <TagC attr3="g12dg" attr4="fgf">
      <TagD attr5="dgs" attr6="furu" />
    </TagC>
    <TagC attr3="fh5yg" attr4="ergf">
      <TagD attr5="dgs" attr6="tdru" />
      <TagD attr5="oko" attr6="tsas" />
    </TagC>
  </TagB>
</TagA>
```

The attr3 is unique for each node TagC.

What I need to do is for each node TagC, perform some operation OP1 on the command line and then come back and insert an attribute attr7 (whose value  = output from OP1) to the same node TagC.

I'm trying to achieve this using Python on Ubuntu.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Python has [several options available](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html) in the standard library. The ElementTree API is easiest to use.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232618/adding-attributes-to-existing-elements-removing-elements-etc-with-lxml

Comment: this may help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074021/inserting-xml-nodes-in-an-existing-xml-document-with-python